# Cleaning lower levels of D3 nested data

Tags: d3.js

I am having trouble working with D3 nested data. Currently, my code nests the data by two variables, `leader` and `competent`. Then, the code rolls up the data to get counts per leader-competent survey category.

```
var summary = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.leader})
    .key(function(d) {return d.competent})
        .sortKeys(function(a, b) {return scaleValues.indexOf(a) - scaleValues.indexOf(b)})
    .rollup(function(l) {return l.length})
    .entries(data)
```

Output looks like this:

```
​0: {…}
    ​​key: "John"
    ​​values: (2) […]
    ​​​    0: Object { key: "Agree", value: 3 }
    ​​​    1: Object { key: "Strongly Agree", value: 6 }
    ​​​length: 2
​1: {…}
    key: "Emily"
​​    values: (2) […]
​​​        0: Object { key: "Agree", value: 4 }
​​​        1: Object { key: "Strongly Agree", value: 6 }
​​​    length: 2
length: 2
```

I then clean the data to ensure that missing competent survey categories are added in with counts of `0`.

```
makeAllKeys = function(d) {
    allKeys = scaleValues
        return allKeys
}

summary = summary.map(function(d) {
    return {
        key: d.key,
        values: makeAllKeys(+d.key).map(function(k) {
            value = d.values.filter(function(v) {return v.key == k})[0]
            return value || ({key: k, values:0})
        })
    }
})
```

Output now looks like this:

```
0: {…}
​​    key: "John"
​​​​    values: (5) […]
​​​​​    ​​    0: Object { key: "Strongly Disagree", values: 0 }
​​​​​    ​​    1: Object { key: "Disagree", values: 0 }
​​​​​    ​​    2: Object { key: "Neutral", values: 0 }
​​​​​    ​​    3: Object { key: "Agree", value: 3 }
​​​​​    ​​    4: Object { key: "Strongly Agree", value: 6 }
​​​​​    length: 5
1: {…}
​​​​    key: "Emily"
​​​​    values: (5) […]
​​​​​    ​​    0: Object { key: "Strongly Disagree", values: 0 }
​​​​​    ​​    1: Object { key: "Disagree", values: 0 }
​​​​​    ​​    2: Object { key: "Neutral", values: 0 }
​​​​​    ​​    3: Object { key: "Agree", value: 4 }
​​​​​    ​​    4: Object { key: "Strongly Agree", value: 6 }
​​​​​    length: 5
length: 2
```

Now, I want to add another layer to the nest using `company` as a key.

```
var summary = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.leader})
    .key(function(d) {return d.company})
    .key(function(d) {return d.competent})
        .sortKeys(function(a, b) {return scaleValues.indexOf(a) - scaleValues.indexOf(b)})
    .rollup(function(l) {return l.length})
    .entries(data)
```

Here's how the output looks with the `company` key added:

```
0: {…}
​​​​    key: "John"
​​    ​​    ​​values: (2) […]
​​​​​    ​​    ​​    0: {…}
​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    ​​​​key: "A"
​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    ​​​​values: (2) […]
​​​​​​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    0: Object { key: "Agree", value: 2 }
​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    ​​​​​1: Object { key: "Strongly Agree", value: 3 }
​​​​​​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    length: 2
​​​    ​​    ​​    ​​​1: {…}
​​​​​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    key: "B"
​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    ​​​​values: (2) […]
​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    ​​​​​0: Object { key: "Agree", value: 1 }
​​​​​​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    1: Object { key: "Strongly Agree", value: 3 }
​​​​​​​    ​​    ​​    ​​    length: 2
​​​​​    ​​    length: 2
​1: Object { key: "Emily", values: (2) […] }
​length: 2
```

However, I am struggling to modify the code that fixes the missing survey categories now that they are another level lower in the nested structure.

Full test code and example data provided below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Page Template</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <script type = "text/javascript">

            // Define scales
            var scaleValues = ["Strongly Disagree", "Disagree", "Neutral", "Agree", "Strongly Agree"]
            var scaleValues2 = ["Very Unlikely", "Unlikely", "Neutral", "Likely", "Very Likely"]

            // Import the data
            d3.csv("stackoverflow.csv", function(error, data) {
                if (error) throw error

                var data = data
                    .map(function(d) {return {leader: d.leader, company: d.company, competent: d.competent, personable: d.personable, helpful: d.helpful, recommend: d.recommend}})
                    .filter(function(d) {return d.competent != "NA"})
                    .filter(function(d) {return d.personable != "NA"})
                    .filter(function(d) {return d.helpful != "NA"})
                    .filter(function(d) {return d.recommend != "NA"})
                    .filter(function(d) {return d.leader != "NA"})
                    .filter(function(d) {return d.leader != "I don't remember"})
                data.forEach(function(d) {
                    d.competent = d.competent.replace(/[^a-z0-9+]+/gi, " ")
                    d.personable = d.personable.replace(/[^a-z0-9+]+/gi, " ")
                    d.helpful = d.helpful.replace(/[^a-z0-9+]+/gi, " ")
                    d.recommend = d.recommend.replace(/[^a-z0-9+]+/gi, " ")
                })
                console.log(data)

                makeAllKeys = function(d) {
                    allKeys = scaleValues
                    return allKeys
                }

                var summary = d3.nest()
                    .key(function(d) {return d.leader})
                    // .key(function(d) {return d.company})
                    .key(function(d) {return d.competent})
                        .sortKeys(function(a, b) {return scaleValues.indexOf(a) - scaleValues.indexOf(b)})
                    .rollup(function(l) {return l.length})
                    .entries(data)

                summary = summary.map(function(d) {
                    return {
                        key: d.key,
                        values: makeAllKeys(+d.key).map(function(k) {
                            value = d.values.filter(function(v) {return v.key == k})[0]
                            return value || ({key: k, values:0})
                        })
                    }
                })
                console.log(summary)
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

stackoverflow.csv

```
company,competent,personable,helpful,recommend,leader
A,Agree,Agree,Agree,Likely,John
A,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Agree,Very Unlikely,John
A,Agree,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Very Likely,John
A,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Very Likely,John
A,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Neutral,Very Likely,John
A,Agree,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Very Likely,Emily
A,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Very Likely,Emily
A,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Very Likely,Emily
A,Agree,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Likely,Emily
A,Agree,Strongly Agree,Agree,Neutral,Emily
B,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Very Likely,John
B,Agree,Agree,Agree,Likely,John
B,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Agree,Likely,John
B,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Likely,John
B,Agree,Strongly Agree,Agree,Likely,Emily
B,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Likely,Emily
B,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Very Likely,Emily
B,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Very Likely,Emily
B,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Strongly Agree,Very Likely,Emily
```

Comment: have you looked at your `summary` after the nest operation?

Comment: Yes, it looks normal in both cases (2 keys & 3 keys). I'll put examples in the question.

Comment: if you manage to do it for 1 level, what is the problem for a 2nd level of nesting?

Comment: I've tried many ways of modifying the code that fixes the missing survey categories, but my attempts to reference lower level values doesn't work. For instance, I can't simply say `d.values.key` to refer to the company key in the way that I use `d.key` to refer to the leader key. So my `summary.map()` function only works if the `competent` survey values are at the second level of the nest.

Comment: then I suggest reading a good book/website about JavaScript and see what else the language for features has.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll keep searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minor change:

Within the `summary.map...`, `d.values` would now be an array (due to the `company` key being used in the `nest`), and so you have to map this `d.values` internally just like you did in the previous attempt.

Here's the code change that'll make more sense:

```
 var summary = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.leader})
    .key(function(d) {return d.company})
    .key(function(d) {return d.competent})
        .sortKeys(function(a, b) {return scaleValues.indexOf(a) - scaleValues.indexOf(b)})
    .rollup(function(l) {return l.length})
    .entries(data)
    .map(function(d) {
      return {
        key: d.key,
        values: d.values.map(function (row){ 
          return {
            key: row.key, 
            values: makeAllKeys(+d.key).map(function(k) {
              value = row.values.filter(function(v) {return v.key == k})[0]
              return value || ({key: k, values:0})
            })
          }
        })
    }
})
```

And yes, `.map` can be chained to the `d3.nest` itself.

Now the `summary` would look like the following:

```
[  
{  
  "key":"John",
  "values":[  
     {  
        "key":"A",
        "values":[  
           {  
              "key":"Strongly Disagree",
              "values":0
           },
           {  
              "key":"Disagree",
              "values":0
           },
           {  
              "key":"Neutral",
              "values":0
           },
           {  
              "key":"Agree",
              "value":2
           },
           {  
              "key":"Strongly Agree",
              "value":3
           }
        ]
     },
     {  }
  ]
},
{  
  "key":"Emily",
  "values":[  ]
 }
]
```

Here's a plunkr link for reference: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zz7dsTbmO8dI3n3SKkP3?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad I could help! And yes, you don't have to read a book/website just for this (apart from self-learning). :p You did pretty good there and it's just about practicing adding more console logs and breakpoints (using browser debugger) which helps a lot. Happy coding!